# EF Bulk Insert to SQL Server table with UNIQUEIDENTIFIER column as primary key

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, uniqueidentifier

I am working on an ASP.NET C# web application with Entity Framework and a SQL Server 2017 database.

There is a `Transaction` table with a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` column as its primary key and this key is being using as a foreign key to refer to from a child table.

I am using the EF bulk insert function to insert bulk data into both the tables simultaneously.

Is there a way to generate the GUID value from my C# code and insert the same on `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` columns on both tables?

Comment: Get a guid value using `Guid.NewGuid()` and use that for the related rows.